# Error Trying to Login to Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, admin-panel

Everything used to be working fine. Lately, whenever I try to login to the admin panel, I am getting this error. I tried to google it but couldn't find anything that could help me resolve the issue. I tried [this Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014154/how-to-fix-magento-1-7-developer-mode), The output of the test script was:

```
array(1) {
 [0] => object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)#93 (0) {
 }
}
```

Again I didn't know what it meant. However when I refresh the admin panel link after this error is thrown, it takes me to the admin panel. What went wrong here?

```
Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given
in mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1359

->0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'get_class() exp...', '/chroot/home/sh...', 1359, Array)
->1 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1359): get_class(false)
->2 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(false, 'check', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
->3 mywebsite/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('admin_session_u...', Array)
->4 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(132): Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_u...', Array)
->5 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(73): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('admin', 'password', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
->6 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
->7 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
->8 mywebsite/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
->9 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
->10 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
->11 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
->12 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
->13 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
->14 mywebsite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
->15 mywebsite/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
->16 mywebsite/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
->17 {main}
```

Comment: try disabling the custom  module one by one  and check

Comment: Isn't there any other way? there are many modules but none of them is custom module. Disabling them one by one and then checking is a huge task. Had there been an error because of those files would have been logged in error or exception logs. Every thing is in order there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long while, I have found the cause of this issue. 
Actually a couple of weeks back(since this error started appearing), our hosting sent us an email, identifying some files as **viruses** and asked us to remove them otherwise they were going to block our hosting.

We removed those files but they were actually required by an extension in our magento website. After putting back those files we were able to resolve this issue.

For quick solution we disabled error reporting so that we could keep on using things as they normally were and troubleshoot this problem.

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
```